# Custom Composite Control Binding Issue with Hidden Aggregation

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I'm facing issue while doing aggregation binding the custom control. I m not able to do two-way data binding with the custom control inner element.

**Custom control:**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var PriceRangeComponent = sap.ui.core.Control.extend('PriceRangeComponent', {
        constructor: function(mSettings) {
            sap.ui.core.Control.apply(this, arguments);

            this.ef = new sap.m.Input({
                width: '100px',
                value: mSettings.value,
                enabled: mSettings.enabled
            }).attachChange(function(evt){
                console.log(evt);
            });

            this.setAggregation('_ef', this.ef);
        },

        metadata: {
            properties: {
                enabled: { type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true },
                value: { type: 'String', defaultValue: "" }
            },

            events: {
            },

            aggregations: {
                _ef: { type: 'sap.m.Input', multiple: false, visibility: 'hidden' }
            }
        },

        init: function() {
        },

        renderer: function(oRM, oControl) {
            oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_ef'));
        },

        setValue: function (sValue) {
            this.ef.setValue(sValue);
        },

        setEnabled: function (bValue) {
            this.ef.setEnabled(bValue);
        },

        getValue: function(){
            return this.ef.getProperty("value");
        },

        getEnabled: function(){
            return this.ef.getProperty("enabled");
        }

    });

    PriceRangeComponent.prototype.clone = function(){
        var clone = sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.clone.apply(this, arguments),
            bindingInfo;

        clone.ef.bindProperty("value",this.getBindingInfo("value"));

        return clone;
    };

    return PriceRangeComponent;
})();
```

In the control, i want to do two way data binding with the outer model.

**usage of custom control:**

```
var priceGridwindowShade = new sap.ui.commons.windowshade.WindowShade({
            openFirstSection:false,
            sections:[],
            //layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L9 M9"}),
            width: "800px",

        });

        var oTemplateSection = new sap.ui.commons.windowshade.WindowShadeSection({
            title: {
                parts: [
                    {path: "startRange"},{path: "endRange"}
                ],
                formatter: function(startRange, endRange){
                    //console.log(val);
                    return startRange + " to " + endRange;
                }
            },
            content: [
                new PriceRangeComponent({
                    value: "{startRange}"
                }),

                new sap.m.Input({ // this input is for checking the 2 way data binding
                    width: "80px",
                    value: "{startRange}"
                })
            ]
        });

        priceGridwindowShade.bindAggregation("sections", {
            path: "/items",
            template: oTemplateSection,
            templateShareable: true});

        return priceGridwindowShade;
```

Please help me.
When i just instantiate the control and bind the properties, two-way binding works properly. Just that it stop working when i do the aggregation binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you are not at all setting the properties of your custom control but only the ones of the inner input. Try sth. like this for all setters and remove the getters:

```
setValue: function (sValue) {
  this.setProperty('value', sValue, true /* bSupressInvalidate */);
  this.ef.setValue(sValue);
},
```

And you have to populate the value of your input backwards (do this in `init`):

```
init: function() {
  this.ef = new sap.m.Input({
    width: '100px'
  }).attachChange(function(oEv) {
    this.setValue(oEv.getParameters("value"));
  }.bind(this));

  this.setAggregation('_ef', this.ef);
}
```

Some more remarks:

- For initialization use `init` instead of overriding `constructor`
- Use [AMD](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12024e38385472a89c1ad204e1edb48)

If you use a newer SAPUI5 version (I think 1.58+) you can also have a look into [XML Composite Controls](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/b83a4dcb7d0e46969027345b8d32fd44).

BR
Chris

Comment: attach change is worked for my example. But when I did the declaration in init, my example doesn't work with aggregation binding. Can you please create sample example with aggregation binding with init declaration.

Comment: You might face problems because you are not writing the control data in your renderer. You are probably better of with extending sap.m.Input and leaving the renderer untouched.